# Здравствуйте, как можно записать эти условия на питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x

какой будет код для этого задания?

> (П. Волгин) Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [2125; 665123], которые удовлетворяют следующим условиям:
>
> - Сумма цифр больше 12.
> - Произведение цифр равно нулю.
>
> Найдите количество таких чисел и сумму всех цифр. В ответе запишите сначала количество, а затем остаток от деления суммы всех найденных чисел на 10000.

Правильные ответы: 252089 8527
Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
summa = count = 0
for i in range(2125, 665124):
    numbers = list(str(i))
    summ = sum(map(int, numbers))
    
    if '0' in numbers and summ > 12:
        
        count += 1
        summa += i
        
print(f'Количество - {count}')
print(f'Остаток от деления суммы на 10000 - {summa%10000}')
```

Удалил старое решение (фигня там была). Доработал решение коллеги @YaAlex

Comment: Спасибо, теперь пойду разбираться как работает код

Comment: прошу прощения. комментарии добавить?

Comment: не стоит, я должен сам разобраться

Comment: @MaidLine похвально

Comment: код у вас не оптимизирован, зачем рассматривать все числа, если чисел с цифрой 0, чуть ли не в 7 раз меньше чем остальных.

Comment: @YaAlex прошу прощения, но в данном случае Ваш код такой же, цикл по всем числам

Comment: Если вам нужно сравнить время выполнения, просто запустите мой и свой код. Мой код работает быстрее более чем в два раза....

Answer (score 2):

```
summa = count = 0
for i in range(2125, 665124):
    if '0' in str(i) and sum(map(int, list(str(i)))) > 12:
        count += 1
        summa += i
print(count, summa % 10000)
```

Comment: Я добавил правильные ответы

Comment: если мой ответ помог, отметь его пожалуйста как "верный" (слева от ответа галочка), спасибо!

Comment: вместо двух `if` просто превратите их в один `if … and …`

Comment: Нам не нужно считать числа не включающие в себя 0. Два if тут допустимы для оптимизации

Comment: @YaAlex, `and` и `or` работают лениво.

Comment: то-есть если первое условие верно, то второе проверятся уже не будет?

Comment: `list(str(i))` -> `str(i)`.

Comment: Задача может быть решена без перебора всех чисел.

Comment: Два раза `str(i)`. А он тут "толстый".